# How to get address from bounding box in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

In my application I have an embedded Google map where the user can zoom in/out and move around the map.

I want to display the address that the user is currently looking at.
It is no problem using geocoder to show the address of the location of the center of the current map bounds but if the user is zoomed out so that she sees the entire USA it doesn't make sense to give a detailed address of the some random location in the middle of the country.

What I want is to be able to give an address according to zoom level, i.e. street address when zoomed all the way in and country when zoomed out all the way, etc...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may try setting your [zoom level](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#the_camera_position) as discussed in [Camera and View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#top_of_page).
With corresponding zoom levels, you can expect to see the following details:

- 1: World
- 5: Landmass/continent
- 10: City
- 15: Streets
- 20: Buildings

In addition to that, you may set the bounds of the map which will be visible at the greatest possible zoom level. You can use the `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds bounds, int padding)` to obtain a `CameraUpdate` that changes the camera position such that the given `LatLngBounds` fits entirely within the map, taking into account the padding (in pixels).

For more information and a few code samples, please check the links above.

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't answer my question. You are describing the opposite of what I need i.e. given an address I can move/resize the map to fit that address (I already do this). What I need is: given the map bounds, I want to tell the user what she is viewing.